# How to properly write inputs under the multiple transfer (multiTransfer) on the online etherscan form?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

Problem:
I would like to make a multiple transfer of a token using the web-page:
https://etherscan.io/dapp/0x1C95b093d6C236d3EF7c796fE33f9CC6b8606714#

To reproduce the issue, click on the "Write Contract" tab then in the fields under multi-transfer type under text-fields:

```
[0x123123....,0x4321....]
[600,66]
```

What I get is

> new BigNumber() not a number:
>   0x123123....,0x4321....

Source Code:

```
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Transfers to multiple accounts
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function multiTransfer(address[] memory receivers, uint256[] memory amounts) public {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < receivers.length; i++) {
          transfer(receivers[i], amounts[i]);
        }
    }
```

However, if I use the single-value arrays, it works.

How should I write/delimit the inputs ?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, have you figured out the solution to entering an array via etherscan?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, addresses in quotes, like this:

`["0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c","0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c"]`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Same thing (tried just now), I've also tried single quote, { brackets, ... quotes around numbers... nothing worked.  I doubt that contract is wrong, just parsing of an input... I hope.